# Help understanding what abstract algebra question is asking.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $I(G)$ be the set of all inner automorphisms of $G$. Show that $\varphi(a) = f_a$ is a homomorphism of $G$ onto $I(G)$.

Is this asking to prove that the Euler phi-function is a homomorphism of $G$ onto $I(G)$? If so, doesn't $G$ have to operate over the integers? Why wasn't that stated?

Or is this asking to prove that any arbitrarily defined function is a homomorphism of $G$ onto $I(G)$? That doesn't really make sense to me either. What if I define a function that maps every value in $G$ to an arbitrary element in $G$ that is neither the identity nor a generator? That's definitely not a homomorphism of $G$ onto $I(G)$.

Clearly I'm misreading/not understanding something.

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to read the part where they defined $\varphi(a)$ as conjugation by $a$.

Comment: That's what $f_a$ means? Conjugation by a?

Comment: Please cite the source you are reading from.

Comment: This is from a class assignment, and stated pretty much exactly as I've written. We've been using "A first course in abstract algebra" by John B. Fraleigh, but the notation in the book and on assignments sometimes (rarely) differs. The full question is:                                                          Let $I(G)$ be the set of all inner automorphisms of $G$ and $A(G)$ be the set of all automorphisms of $G$. a) Show that $I(G)$ is a subgroup of $A(G)$. b) Show that $\varphi(a)=f_a$ is a homomorphism of $G$ onto $I(G)$.

Comment: Would the conjugation by a be implied, maybe? Is that the most reasonable assumption?

Comment: That is almost certainly what it's supposed to be. There is no universal letter+subscript combo to denote conjugation (and certainly $\varphi$ is not the totient function, which is just, no), but the map $G\to {\rm Inn}(G)$ is always talked about in textbooks so it's easy to infer that's what's being discussed here. Is it possible the assignment is referencing notation introduced somewhere (for example, notes or class lecture) and you just missed it? (I ask, because it would be weird to use the notation without explaining it to students, not because I have any doubt.)

Comment: phi is just notation.  It's not the euler phi-function.  It's defined as stated: phi(a) = f_a.  I'm pretty sure f_a is just conjugation by a, with the inverse on the left of the element being conjugated.

Comment: @anon It's very possible. I got this after the class in which it was originally given.

Comment: From the context I would guess this means show that the map $\varphi: G \to I(G)$ where $a\mapsto f_a$ is a surjective homomorphism ($f_a(x)=a^{-1}xa$)

Comment: Conjugation by a it is! Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been resolved in the comments.